# Get mtime of specific file using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am well aware of being able to do `find myfile.txt -mtime +5` to check if my file is older than 5 days or not. However I would like to fetch mtime in days of myfile.txt and store it into a variable for further usage. How would I do that?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`stat` can give you that info:

```
filemtime=$(stat -c %Y myfile.txt)
```

`%Y` gives you the last modification as "seconds since The Epoch", but there are lots of other options; [more info](https://manpages.debian.org/stat). So if the file was modified on 2011-01-22 at 15:30 GMT, the above would return a number in the region of 1295710237.

**Edit**: Ah, you want the time in days since it was modified. That's going to be more complicated, not least because a "day" is not a fixed period of time (some "days" have only 23 hours, others 25 — thanks to daylight savings time).

The *naive* version might look like this:

```
filemtime=$(stat -c %Y "$1")
currtime=$(date +%s)
diff=$(( (currtime - filemtime) / 86400 ))
echo $diff
```

...but again, that's assuming a day is always exactly 86,400 second long.

More about arithmetic in bash [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/arithmetic_expressions.shtml).

Comment: That was sweet, unfortunately I've made a fool of myself and forgot that I needed the mtime age in days. Is that possible?

Comment: @Industrial: Once you have the value, you can do math on it. I don't follow what you mean by "...the mtime age in days." (Days since when? You mean, how many days ago it was modified?)

Comment: @TJ Crowder: Thanks. What I mean, to clarify, is that I need the number of whole days since the file was modified

Comment: @Industrial: Gotcha. Updated.

Comment: Word of warning: `stat` options are not at all portable across systems. FreeBSD, for example, requires `stat -f %m` for the same thing (argh!). The `stat` utility is not defined in POSIX.

Answer (score 8):

The date utility has a convenient switch for extracting the mtime from a file, which you can then display or store using a format string.

```
date -r file "+%F"
# 2021-01-12
file_mtime=$(date -r file "+%F")
```

See `man date`, the output of date is controlled by a format string beginning with `"+"`

Useful format strings for comparing many dates might include:

```
"+%j": day of year
"+%s": unix epoch time
```

Arithmetic with dates is a bit of a pain in bash, so if you need relative time that will work in all corner cases, you may be better off with another language.

Answer (score 4):

```
AGE=$(perl -e 'print -M $ARGV[0]' $file)
```

will set $AGE to the age of $file in days, as Perl's `-M` operator handles the `stat` call and the conversion to days for you.

The return value is a floating-point value (e.g., 6.62849537 days). Add an `int` to the expression if you need to have an integer result

```
AGE=$(perl -e 'print int -M $ARGV[0]' $file)
```

Ruby and Python also have their one-liners to stat a file and return some data, but I believe Perl has the most concise way.

Answer (score 3):

I this the answer?

```
A=$(stat -c "%y" myfile.txt)
```

look at stat-help

```
stat --help
Usage: stat [OPTION]... FILE...
Display file or file system status.
[...]
-c  --format=FORMAT   use the specified FORMAT instead of the default;
                      output a newline after each use of FORMAT
[...]
The valid format sequences for files
[...]
  %y   Time of last modification, human-readable
  %Y   Time of last modification, seconds since Epoch
[...]
```